# how can cashed chat when pusher channel will disconnect or internet will turn off in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

actually i am working with the chat app with Laravel backend support. i received message using pusher channel. the problem is cashes chat for offline mode as like other chat apps.

is SQFlite solution or any other way to make is easier?

Comment: Can you please add some more details on what you're asking? Are you wanting to cache the chat when the app goes offline?

Comment: use Hive or ObjectBox for saving messages to local storage